# How can i check if some dir exist and then execute in makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I have this in my `Makefile`

```
venv:
    virtualenv /var/www/env && source /var/www/env/bin/activate
```

But i only want to do that if  `/var/www/env` does not exist

How can i do that

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `make` rules do not support negative conditions.

A common workaround is to use dummy files to mark a condition; in this case you could have something like

```
var-www-env-does-not-exist:
    if [ -d /var/www/env ]; then touch $@; else rm -f $@; exit 1; fi

venv: var-www-env-does-not-exist /var/www/env/bin/activate
    virtualenv /var/www/env && source /var/www/env/bin/activate
```

Another idea is to write and call a script that calls `virtualenv` but also correctly deals with the case of an existing `/var/www/env`.